# OpenMP construct to continue execution as soon as at least 1 thread is finished

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a need to continue execution as soon as one of the threads has finished execution. The logic inside the parallel section with ensure that everything has been completed satisfactorily. I have nested parallelisation therefore I put some of the top level threads to Sleep when data is not ready to be processed as not to consume computation power. So when one of the top level threads finishes I want to continue execution and not wait for the other threads to wake up and naturally return.

I use

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(wanted_thread_no)
```

Comment: if the outer loop has N iterations and the inner loop has M (for each of N), do you want any of the outer loops

Comment: The inner is a dependancy tree/graph with N children over many branches. The other loop looks to find branches which can be updated independant of other branches

Answer (score 0):

How do you parallelise? Do you use tasks, sections or?

If I understood correct and if you using the task primitive you can use the `#pragma omp parallel nowait` after the last task.

Check this pdf on page 13 (of the pdf).

http://openmp.org/wp/presos/omp-in-action-SC05.pdf

It explicitly says:

> By default, there is a barrier at the end of the “omp for”. Use the
>   “nowait” clause to turn off the barrier.
>   `#pragma omp for nowait` “nowait” is useful between two consecutive, independent omp for loops.

Is this what you want?

Also take a look on this as well, even if it says the same thing.

http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf

Comment: thank for the idea. from what I have read - nowait means that none of the threads have completed. I need at least 1 thread to complete, then I will know that all the other threads don't have any work left to do.